# Android Firebase how to use the spacial characters in the childs

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in Firebase realtime database, and I have to save some special characters in the database like the following:

```
https://myProject.firebaseio.com/myProject/en/$fanny/weight
```

*Note: the child could contain any special character not just only $*

How could I handle such like this issue please?

As I see there are some guys are replacing the characters, but in my case I should not change the values, because I have to display it to the users as is because it has a meaningful to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution is to replace the invalid characters in the keys.

If you need to display the original value to the user, also store it as a value.