# Firebase create issue with special Character

Tags: json, xml, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an issue if I try to import json into firebase with uni-coded for special character, so firebase refused and show error that your json contain some prohibited character like #, $, ' etc.

But I have in my json all these special characters, so how I cope with this issue any suggestions or help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the JSON you are trying to import. Does this JSON validate?

Comment: Firebase keys cannot contain those characters. You will need to change them before trying to import. Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750728/android-firebase-how-to-use-the-spacial-characters-in-the-childs/42750884#42750884) as well